# Can't find the relation between two inequalities but they are obviously related

Tags: calculus

I must prove that [image] for n natural and bigger than one. In the previous question, I managed to prove that [image] (log means the natural logarithm, not base 10), and I'm pretty sure these two are related and I may use one to prove the other. I have already tried another methods, such as induction (couldn't complete the induction step) and proving that the difference between the two is always negative(couldn't take the derivative). I don't know how to proceed.

Computed some values just to make sure they are related:

```
n = 2
0.3862943611198906
0.34657359027997264
2
2.081040380091556
--------------------
n = 3
1.2958368660043291
1.242453324894
6
6.329004838808519
--------------------
n = 4
2.5451774444795623
2.484906649788
24
25.490979004346343
--------------------
n = 5
4.047189562170502
3.9827727865649956
120
127.98441752046358
--------------------
n = 6
5.750556815368331
5.683371477396074
720
770.0354478695812
--------------------
n = 7
7.621371043387192
7.552206286537758
5040
5400.928260732347
--------------------
n = 8
9.635532333438686
9.564882131905334
40320
43271.65602044078
--------------------
n = 9
11.775021196025975
11.703215191413362
362880
389895.28602964873
--------------------
n = 10
14.02585092994046
13.953120026578494
3628800
3902560.665090633
```

Comment: Look up stuff on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: BTW, "ln" is unambiguous about meaning the natural log rather than the common log. In this case, it doesn't really matter; all the terms in your inequality contain a log, and changing the base just multiplies by a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you've shown that
$$
\int_1^n \log x dx> \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \log k\right)- \frac12\log n.
$$

First, of all using the fact that $\log a+ \log b= \log(ab)$ we see that the RH is equal to
$$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \log k\right)- \frac12\log n= \log(1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots \cdot n)- \log\sqrt{n}= \log\frac{n!}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$
Moreover, for the LHS, we have that $(x\log x- x)'= \log x$, thus
$$
\int_1^n\log xdx= [x\log x-x]_1^n= n\log n-n+1= \log n^n-\log e^n+\log e= \log\frac{n^n\cdot e}{e^n}.
$$
As a result, the inequality becomes
$$
\log\frac{n^n\cdot e}{e^n}> \log\frac{n!}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
that is
$$
\frac{n^n\cdot e}{e^n}> \frac{n!}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: I feel like I really slept on this log manipulations and properties. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\right)=n!$$
and
$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log n\right) = \sqrt{n}$$
so it suffices to show that
$$\exp\left(\int_1^n\log x\, dx\right) \le \frac{n^ne}{e^n}.$$
You can compute this integral explicitly.